# How to read the content instead of transcluding in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a UI which a user can customize. My UI model is based on JSON but for end-users they want to customize this in such a way that they will provide some specific markup in HTML. Instead of transcluding that content, they want the outer directive to parse it and process it. In the real scenario, the outer directive has a table element in its template. The inner markup just tells this directive that which all columns provided in the JSON model need to be shown.

To understand this better, here is a simplified example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Denero/fdhd0z9c/3/)

As you can see, inside the `div` that uses the directive `my-angular-dir1`, there are some content that are not supposed to be transcluded as it is:

```
<I>
<br>&lt;div my-angular-dir1>
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;    &lt;div my-angular-dir2="myData.node1"></div>
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;    &lt;div my-angular-dir2="myData.node2"></div>
<br>&lt;/div>
</I>
```

My requirement now is, to be able to get the inner markup like `<I>&lt;div my-angular-dir2="myData.node1">&lt;/div></I>` in the link function(or somewhere else) of `my-angular-dir1`, so that I can use that information to decide what needs to be shown by the outer directive.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpzrLefj/)

You need to use manual transclusion and take advantage of the template function.  transclude: true unfortunately removes the content before the template function is called, hence the need for manual transclusion.

```
app.directive('myAngularDir1', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: function (tElement, tAttr) {
            console.log('template: ' + tElement.html());

            var content = tElement.children();
            content.remove();
            //process the content using a service (not shown)
            var processedContent = angular.element('<div>ProcessedContent</div>');
            //re-add to the directive
            tElement.append(processedContent);
            return '<div>Label: <input type="text" ng-model="myData.name">' + tElement.html() + '</div>'
        },
        replace: true,
        compile: function (element, attr) {

            console.log('compile: ' + element.html());

            //we are going to need to do manual transclusion:
            var transcludedContent = element.children();
            element.children().remove();
            return function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                // How to get the content like:
                //  <div my-angular-dir2="myData.node1"></div>
                // that is in inside the current div in the HTML ??

                console.log('link: html: ' + element.html());

                //finish the manual transclusion
                var newScope = scope.$parent.$new();
                element.append($compile(transcludedContent)(newScope));


            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I would be able to adopt it. We need to use template as that is another way of extending this UI. But we should still be able to use it I guess, by loading the template dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive like this:

```
app.directive('outer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        console.log(clone.html());
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then if your HTML looks like this:

```
<outer>hello</outer>
```

You won't see "hello" written to the DOM, but you will see it written via the `console.log` call. Inside the `transclude` function you have access to the inner elements and you can decide what to do with them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, helpful to understand.
Although with this I get the element as already processed
e.g.
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" my-angular-dir2="myData.node2">{{node.name}}</div>

rather than
<div my-angular-dir2="myData.node2"></div>